# How to display network of duplicates?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

It is not uncommon with situation where e.g. question A is a duplicate of B and C, B is a duplicate of D, and B is a duplicate of C. You get a directional network of duplicates.

Is there any simple way to see the full network starting from one question? That is, starting from any one of A, B, C or D get the full list of all four "duplicate relatives"?

If it at least was somehow possible to find "reverse duplicates" (that is every question that is marked as a duplicate of X) I could find them all manually. Is there a way?

Comment: In [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) look at the [PostLinks](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/554944) table

Comment: @rene Thanks for the tip! I made a query for the reverse duplicate: http://data.stackexchange.com/security/query/554992/find-reverse-duplicates Will see if I can manage to get it to spit out the full graph.